# ASP.NET: I'm having trouble getting file path's to work on my Master Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have a master page I made with a navigational menu.  I use this master page on my file `default.aspx` and also `pro/page.aspx`. The image and link references don't match up depending on which page I'm on.  I attempted something like `~/page.aspx?function=a` && `~/Images/menu/a.gif`. However these don't work. I can get the paths to work in certain cases, but then they never work on the other page.  Can anyone point me in the direction of a fix for this? Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `~` (root) operator with html tags. Please include `markup` in your post.

Comment: @AVD, My apologies..., why won't `/page.aspx?function=a` work? Is there something I need to set up that I am not?

Comment: You can't. Add `runat=server` attribute to html tag : `<a runat="server" href="~/page.aspx?function=3">Something</a>`

Comment: @AVD, thanks bud that worked perfectly.  If you want to submit that as an answer I'll gladly mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got working. Please accept Maxim Paukov's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the ~ operator in any path-related property in **server controls**. The ~ operator is recognized **only for server controls and in server code**. You cannot use the ~ operator for client elements.

For example:

```
<asp:image runat="server" id="Image1"
  ImageUrl="~/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

[MSDN: ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Any HTML element on a page can be converted to an HTML **server control** by adding the attribute **runat="server"**.

[MSDN: ASP.NET Web Server Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyt68f1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)